# ChartJS Horizontal Bar is displaying backwards

Tags: npm, chart.js, vue-chartjs

This happened recently. I think it has to do with updating NPM packages but I tried rolling back my package.json to what I have in production and it didn't work.

When I switch it to a regular bar chart (vs horizontal) they go the right way

There are no error messages

Using:

vue-chartjs: v3.4.2

chart.js: 2.8.0

[image: Bars go left when they should go right]

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this issue, try removing the afterBuildTicks setting and the chart should display correctly